# How to make visual studio (2019) open new files always as a tab in the current window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I often use various hotkeys to navigate files in a codebase using Visual Studio 2019:

- ctrl+, lets me type a filename, and hitting enter opens that file
- I have ctrl+a mapped to toggle between .cpp and .h files
- I use ctrl+] to "go to definition", etc...

I also often use a split frame: my "workspace" consists of two views of files, side by side, and each has its own list of open tabs.

The behavior I would like to force is, if I use a shortcut to open a new file (or really attempt to open a file by any means...), it should open that file *in the current frame*.

In fact, that IS the behavior if either A. the current frame already has the target file in an open tab, or B. neither frame has the target file open in a tab.

But when the other frame has the target file in a tab, VS switches focus to the other frame and selects that tab.

This makes it very difficult to keep one frame open as a reference, and the other as an active development buffer, as VS keeps shuffling them from under me.